# Event triggering inside prototype

Tags: javascript

When I try to call "Test" function I get an error.
How to fix that? (no jquery!)

Browser:firefox
 error:

> TypeError: this.Test is not a function

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">



            MyClass = function(){
            }

            MyClass.prototype = {

                Init: function(){
                    var txt = document.getElementById("text");

                    if (txt.addEventListener) {
                        txt.addEventListener("keyup", this.Foo, true)
                    }


                },

                Foo: function(){
                    this.Test();
                },

                Test: function(){
                    alert('OK');
                }


            }
            window.onload = function(){
                obj = new MyClass;
                obj.Init();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="text" rows="10">
    </textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the error?  What browser?  IE doesn't support addEventListener(), it uses attachEvent().

This is why most people use a framework like JQuery or YUI, etc...

Comment: puh-leeze when you get an error, *quote* it in your question.

Comment: I think you could use jQuery for this.

Comment: @Matthew Smith, browser:firefox   error: TypeError: this.Test is not a function

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen  as i noted, no JQUERY  PURE JAVASCRIPT

Comment: @shivesh: I think you could use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you reference `this.Foo` as the event, what actually happens is that it copies that function out of the object scope, ergo `this` does not exist. What most people do is use an anonymous function / wrapper around the event.

Comment: `this` does exist: at the moment the event fires, it is set to element `textarea#text`.

Comment: @shivesh something like this? 
`var self = this; txt.addEventListener("keyup", function(){ self.Foo(); }, true);`

@Marcel That's not completely true in this scenario, most JS libraries make sure that `this` is the element, but in native javascript that behaviour is not 100% cross browser proof.

Comment: That's right, but the OP is using Firefox and `addEventListener`.